# z-Index Issue with jqGrid and Wijmo WijMenu

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, z-index, wijmo

I am trying to use the jQuery-based Wijmo WijMenu control with jqGrid in order to create a dynamic grid toolbar.

[image]

Getting the menu to appear works fine.  However, my menuitem1 has a submenu, and this submenu falls behind the jqGrid when I hover over 'menuitem1'.

I've tried setting the z-Index on the menu and the individual menu items, but with no luck.  This behavior happens on IE9, Chrome, FF and Safari.  It does work when I turn compatibility mode on with IE9, which makes me think it may have something to do with the z-index...but I'm not sure.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/pKk3P/6/) to demonstrate my issue.

Can anyone help me get the submenu to fall in front of the jqGrid?

Thank you in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a z-index issue. The .ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata has overflow:hidden on it. Try making it overflow: visible.

Although I'm not sure if it will cause problems on the grid when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS from

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata {
    border-left: 0px none;
    border-right: 0px none;
    height: 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata {
    border-left: 0px none;
    border-right: 0px none;
    height: 21px;
}
```

Removing the `overflow:hidden` It was hiding your menu.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm marking JEBR0 as the answer since his was entered first.  Thank you.