# jqGrid's header section hiding a dropdown

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, jqgrid

EDIT: Since I didn't get any responses, I am going to add more details to this question.

I use the dropdown menu provided at: http://codecanyon.net/item/drop-menu/81289 (paid for it).

The following code is the HTML as well as the java script to construct the menu:

```
<div id="divMenu" style="position: relative">
    <ul id="nav-one" class="dropmenu">
        <li>
            <a id="a1" href="#divManageXXXX">Manage XXXXXYYYYY</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="aManageX" href="#divManageX">Manage X</a></li>
                <li><a id="aManageY" href="#divManageY">Manage Y</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="aManageZZZZZ" href="#divManageZZZZ">Manage ZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="aManageZ1" href="#ManageZ1">Manage Z1</a></li>
                <li><a id="aManageZ2" href="#ManageZ2">Manage Z2</a></li>
                <li><a id="aManageZ3" href="#ManageZ3">Manage Z3</a></li>                        
                <li><a id="aManageZ4" href="#ManageZ4">Manage Z4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="aManageS" href="#">Manage S</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="aManageS1" href="#ManageS1">Manage S1</a></li>
                <li><a id="aManageS2" href="#ManageS2">Manage S2</a></li>
                <li><a id="aManageS3" href="#Manage S3">Manage S3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="" href="#">Manage B</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="aManageB1" href="#ManageB1">Manage B1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The code to initialize this is:

```
jQuery('#nav-one').dropmenu({ openClick: true });
```

Apart from this, I have defined jqGrid as follows:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="divMain">
   <div id="divManageX">
      <table>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
              <table id="tblManageX"></table>
              <div id="divManageY"></div>
          </tr>
      </table>          
   </div>
   <div id="ManageY">
   .....
   </div>
</div>
```

The code to initialize the jqGrid is very simple, it is present across this website and others.

The issue: When the dropdown menu expands on click, if there is a jqGrid in the background then the dropdown menu item is hidden behind the jqGrid as shown in the image below:

[image: Drop down menu hidden]

Comment: Also, based on the suggestion on the code canyon website I also added a CSS selector ”.dropmenu li > ul, .dropmenu li > div” with a z-index value of 9999 to the CSS of the drop down menu.

Comment: Also, I used the Superfish drop down menu: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/ and I see the same issue.

Comment: Can you get support from the author? What is the z-index of the jqGrid table? Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: These two SO questions talk about jqGrid:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778734/z-index-issue-with-jqgrid-and-wijmo-wijmenu  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273493/jqgrid-inside-jquery-simple-modal-problems-with-z-index-in-edit-delete-add-popup

Comment: I've looked at both of those questions. I implemented the solution of the first question and it didn't work. Also, first question is about jqGrid menu and the second is with regards to jqGrid edit forms. I believe that these will behave differently.

Comment: Also, the author mentioned the addition of a CSS selector ”.dropmenu li > ul, .dropmenu li > div” with a z-index value of 9999 in his/her comments.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get very good help without have a live demonstration of the issue for us to look at.

Comment: I agree. As a matter of fact, I am planning on putting something together on JSFiddle to try and demonstrate the same. This will be my first time using JSFiddle, which is why it'll take some time. Thanks a lot for your interest in trying to solve my issue.